# MariaDB user-defined function returns int or null when decimal expected

Tags: mysql, function, mariadb

I am exploring the depths of user-defined functions in MariaDB version 5.5.35 running on Slackware64 14.1.

The function is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(st_id tinyint, pol_id tinyint, month_sel tinyint, year_sel smallint)
-> RETURNS DECIMAL(7.4)
-> DETERMINISTIC
-> BEGIN
-> DECLARE avrg decimal;
-> SELECT avg(value) into avrg FROM all_data_obs
-> WHERE month(start_time)=month_sel and year(start_time)=year_sel and station_id=st_id and polutant_id=pol_id;
-> RETURN avrg;
-> END $$
```

DB says

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

But when I try to use it like

```
select avg_month(2,5,5,2014);
```

It returns either null or 1 or 0. Shouldn't it be 1.0 or 0.0? And 
If I try to use it like

```
select avg_month(16,5,5,2014) from all_data_obs;
```

the DB never returns anything and I have to stop the query with ctrl+c

If I use only the select statement, it works fine. For example

```
 SELECT avg(value) as a FROM all_data_obs WHERE month(start_time)=5 and year(start_time)=2014 and station_id=16 and polutant_id=5;
```

returns  0.122427, but

```
select avg_month(16,5,5,2014);
```

returns 0

I admit I am new to functions. I asked Google and read several articles on how to write functions but couldn't find how to solve this.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to add (7,4) when declaring avrg:

```
DECLARE avrg DECIMAL(7,4);
```

Now everything looks fine.

I will also put here my other mistakes which were pointed out to me previously:

- I wrote RETURNS DECIMAL(7.4) instead of (7,4)
- The function was incorrectly declared as DETERMINISTIC.

Those two were noticed by @Andomar.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared your function `DETERMINISTIC`.  [Which means that:](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/create-function/)

> A function is deterministic if it can produce only one result for a
>   given list of parameters. If the result may be affected by stored
>   data, server variables, random numbers or any value that is not
>   explicitly passed, then the function is not deterministic.

Since you're querying from a table, your function should not be declared as deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the help in clarifying the deterministic/ not deterministic dilemma. I thought it was a completely different thing. I changed it to NOT deterministic but the return value is still 0.

Comment: You're using a dot in `decimal(7.4)`. [Try a comma?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-documentation/data-types/data-types-numeric-data-types/decimal/)

Comment: You are right, of course. Now I get 0.000 every time except for the month with no data where it is  NULL.